# CURL GET Request redirects me to a 404 Error , although the URL works perfectly

Tags: php, curl

I have a simple `testapi.php` page and the following code:

```
<?php
function simpleResponse(){
    $ch = curl_init("http://api.predator.wtf/resolver/?arguments=live:eureka_7");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
}

simpleResponse();
?>
```

What it should do is echo this: http://puu.sh/jxrgT.png

But what actually happens is that first I see some Chinese Letters then after 1 second I get redirected to the hosting company 404 page.

I changed the API and it worked, but why doesn't it work with this specific API? Is there something wrong here? Both of them should work the same.

Why does this API work fine?: vbooter.org/api/skype.php?username=live:eureka_7&proxy-detect=1

While the other just gives me the Chinese letters then a fast redirection to the 404 page.

By the way, I have deleted the default.php + .htaccess files on my host. (Don't need them for now.)

And here is the weird thing:

I tried to open my website with viewsource:mywebsite and here is the code I found even though I didn't put it on my website at all, and neither is it in the API:

```
<html><body><br><br><br>
<script>window.location="/resolver/?arguments=live:eureka_7&jdfwkey=rkejl1";</script>
<script>var u=2;for(;u==1;u++);</script><br><br><br><center><h3>
<a href="/resolver/?arguments=live:eureka_7&jdfwkey=rkejl1">
<p>如果您的页面没有自动跳转，请点击这里</p></a></h3></center></body></html>
```

Comment: It works for me like 80% of the time - occationally getting "Crap, No IP Was Found!" - other times, getting "24.52.35.208" - PS: this url also sends UTF8 with BOM, meaning the 3 first bytes will be the BOM bytes, which might look like chinese characters or whatever.. to get rid of them: $response=substr($response,3);

Answer (score 0):

From local tests here, I have found the following:
When you access "http://api.predator.wtf/resolver/?arguments=live:eureka_7", the host will reply with `´╗┐Crap, No IP Was Found!` or `24.52.35.208`

It does seems that the server may be overrun by requests, and is dropping or not being able to perform all actions that is programmed to.

When using translate.google.com, the `如果您的页面没有自动跳转，请点击这里` means `If your browser does not support frames, please click here`.

And it does seems that there are headers missing on the request.
From the syntax, it looks like it is PHP on the other hand, and a variable such as `($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])` might be missing. Most browsers will append info to their headers, and fix this, but cUrl wont.

Answer (score -2):

I guess that the API you are using , sends that html code as a response to your browser.

It's basically like a firewall , to prevent leechers , like you Lol.